# Laravel modify route parameter to name column instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5, http-status-code-404

In my `web.php` file, I specify the following route:

```
Route::get('/{project}', 'ProjectsController@index');
```

In my ProjectsController, I define the public function `index` as follows:

```
use App\Project;
// ... Here is the class declaration etc.
public function index(Project $project) {
  dd($project->name);
}
```

Currently, I have one entry in my projects table, which I can call without any problems over my eloquent model. This is my entry:

```
Name: sampleproject
Description: This is a test.
ID: 1
// And the timestamps...
```

When calling `/sampleproject`, it returns a 404 error page.
[...]

**UPDATE:** When calling `/1`, which is the project id, everything works as expected. How can I modify my code so I can call my Controller over the project name, not the id?

Comment: You can look the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @VincentDecaux I´ve read through that page, but I seem to have overlooked that section. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your model:

```js
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'yourcolumn';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append your "project" parameter in the URL with ":name", so before appending your parameter is:

```
Route::get('/{project}', 'ProjectsController@index');
```

and after appending, your Route would look like this:

```
Route::get('/{project:name}', 'ProjectsController@index');
```